# How to automate selection of a particular date from calendar in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

I have a case in which I have to pick 3 days back date from the calendar.How to automate this case using selenium.I am using java with selenium for automation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Assumption is that you can write the date in the input field and calendar is only the icon. You can have helper method something like this

```
    public String threeDaysBefore(){
    String threeDaysBefore = "";
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);

    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3);
    Date before = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
    threeDaysBefore = formatter.format(before);
    return threeDaysBefore;
}
```

And later in the code

```
  WebElement calendarManualInput = driver.findElement...// find the manual input field
  calendarManualInput.sendKeys(threeDaysBefore());
```

2) If you can only click the calendar, It would be little more tricky. You still need the String, but little different:

```
    public String threeDaysBefore(){
    String threeDaysBefore = "";
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);

    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3);
    Date before = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    threeDaysBefore = formatter.format(before);
    return threeDaysBefore;
}
```

But the above has little catch. If the date is 1.4. then it will return you "29" which could be interpreted as 29.4. which you dont want to happen. So later in the code you will probably have to do this

```
//this will click three days before
Date today = new Date();
Date minusThree = new Date();
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.setTime(today);
Calendar before = Calendar.getInstance();
before.setTime(minusThree);
before.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -3);
int monthNow = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int monthBefore = before.get(Calendar.MONTH);

if (monthBefore < monthNow){
  // click previous month in the calendar tooltip on page
}
WebElement dateToSelect = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='"+threeDaysBefore()+"']"));
dateToSelect.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

here i show you my orignal code for automating jqueryui calender from its official site "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html".

copy paste the code and see it working like charm :)

vote up if you like it :) regards Avadh Goyal

```
public class calendarHanding {

static int targetDay = 4, targetMonth = 6, targetYear = 1993;

static int currenttDate = 0, currenttMonth = 0, currenttYear = 0;

static int jumMonthBy = 0;

static boolean increment = true;

public static void getCurrentDayMonth() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    currenttDate = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    currenttMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    currenttYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}

public static void getTargetDayMonthYear(String dateString) {
    int firstIndex = dateString.indexOf("/");
    int lastIndex = dateString.lastIndexOf("/");

    String day = dateString.substring(0, firstIndex);
    targetDay = Integer.parseInt(day);

    String month = dateString.substring(firstIndex + 1, lastIndex);
    targetMonth = Integer.parseInt(month);

    String year = dateString.substring(lastIndex + 1, dateString.length());
    targetYear = Integer.parseInt(year);

}

public static void calculateToHowManyMonthToJump() {

    if ((targetMonth - currenttMonth) > 0) {
        jumMonthBy = targetMonth - currenttMonth;

    } else {
        jumMonthBy = currenttMonth - targetMonth;
        increment = false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String dateToSet = "16/12/2016";

    getCurrentDayMonth();
    System.out.println(currenttDate);
    System.out.println(currenttMonth);
    System.out.println(currenttYear);

    getTargetDayMonthYear(dateToSet);
    System.out.println(targetDay);
    System.out.println(targetMonth);
    System.out.println(targetYear);

    calculateToHowManyMonthToJump();
    System.out.println(jumMonthBy);
    System.out.println(increment);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\ashutosh.dobhal\\Desktop\\Software\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to(
            "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='datepicker']")).click();

    for (int i = 0; i < jumMonthBy; i++) {
        if (increment) {
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/a[2]/span"))
                    .click();
        } else {
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/a[1]/span"))
                    .click();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    driver.findElement(By.linkText(Integer.toString(targetDay))).click();

}
}
```