# How to handle calendar popup using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, webdriver

How can I select date from a calendar popup like this gender (i.e 24/04/2015 from calendar) using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

I have tried this:

```
package com.Automation;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class CalendarPopup {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.yatra.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("//div[2]/ul[3]/li[1]/i")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("a_2015_4_25")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been answered on stackoverflow, link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398575/select-a-date-from-date-picker-using-selenium-webdriver/21479270#21479270

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click a day by selecting it from its id and then click on it

```
driver.findElement(By.id('a_2015_4_24')).click(); //use this format a_yyyy_m_d
```

you can also go back or forward by clicking the calendar arrows:

```
driver.findElement(By.className('js_btnNext')).click() // click the "next" arrow
driver.findElement(By.className('js_btnPrev')).click() // click the "prev" arrow
```

note that you cannot click past days or days that are not visible, also the calendar must be visible when you click the day.

EDIT: your are selecting wrongly your elements in your code, as you are selecting an element by id passing an xpath to the function, it should be like this:

```
//....
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/ul[3]/li[1]/i")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id('a_2015_4_24')).click();
//...
```

Comment: not in webdriver's APIs, you should use your code to get the date you want and then build your id string by doing "a" + year.toString() + "_" + etc.

Comment: check this answer for more infos about comparing dates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118029/how-to-automate-selection-of-a-particular-date-from-calendar-in-selenium-using-j?rq=1

Comment: remember that in stackoverflow you should mark  as accepted the answer that answers best your questions