# Selecting Calendar Control in Edge using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a date from a date picker in MS Edge using Selenium.  I have tried the following:

```
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    string s_today = today.AddMonths(2).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    IWebElement endDate= Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='date']")); endDate.SendKeys(s_today);
```

And I even tried to create a method that takes that date reformats it and then sends that date to the date picker control

```
string dt = String.Format("{0:MMddyyyy}", s_today);
endDate.SendKeys(dt);
endDate.SendKeys("{Tab}");
```

I cannot seem to seem to select a date.  I reviewed the link below and found nothing.  Please help me. This is a ReactJS web app. Attached are screen shots.

> [How to automate selection of a particular date from calendar in selenium using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118029/how-to-automate-selection-of-a-particular-date-from-calendar-in-selenium-using-j)

[Date Picker in Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8oqq.png)

[DOM for Date Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMx27.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but this is a confirmed bug in the Edge implementation of those particular input types.

Refer to the [Cannot SendKeys on input control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8515651/) bug report on the edge bug tracker.

You can work around the problem by using JavascriptExecutor in selenium, or directly calling /session/:sessionId/execute and injecting your script in the Http request.

Regardless, at the moment it boils down to implementing your own sendKeys in javascript and injecting the javascript using selenium.